# TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseHref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-builder

I wanted to create webpack configuration for angular 7. I have followed the following tutorial - http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2018/12/how-to-customize-build-configuration.html.
I am using  - @angular-builders package 
I have also checked my index.html,it contains base href

[image: error]

I have changed the following things in angular.json -

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/v2/",....
  "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",....
```

Comment: Which versions are you using? Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: Komal, do you have fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In `angular.json` add the baseHref

```
  "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref" : "/v2/",
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that too , but it is not working. I am getting the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because the `@angular-builders/dev-server` library has [this issue](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/196#issuecomment-453017036).

After updating the `package.json` to use to following version, it was resolved.

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "7.2.0",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "7.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.1",
    //rest of the packages
 }
```

NOTE: This should work for both Angular 6 and 7.